# How to solve equations like $\alpha \sin x -\beta\sin 2x +\gamma=0 $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, approximation, newton-raphson

Can I solve this equation without Newton-Raphson method?
I have $\alpha=47.02$ $\beta=112.5$ and $\gamma=50$.
When I have to use Newton-Rapson to solve trigonometric equations ?
I will greatly appreciate your answers.

Comment: Are you asking for a type of closed form for x? Are you asking for different numerical methods?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
Substitute
$$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
the so called Weierstrass substitution.

Comment: This is erroneously called the Weierstrass substitution. James Stewart's widely used calculus textbooks say that Weierstrass pointed it out. Stewart claimed to have learned that elsewhere but said he couldn't remember where. That's the blind leading the blind. I'd call it the tangent half-angle substitution, since $t = \tan\dfrac x 2. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Indeed! I would say that your comment might only be improved by a link to wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution which confirms this.

Comment: Ok, let's say tan half angle substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint:   write it as $\, 2 \beta \sin x \cos x = \alpha \sin x + \gamma\,$, and square both sides. With $\,s = \sin x\,$ the equation then becomes a [depressed quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Converting_to_a_depressed_quartic): $\;4 \beta^2 s^2(1-s^2) = (\alpha s + \gamma)^2\,$.